# 'module' object is not callable error in jupyter notebook

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter

Initially, I was getting "list object is not callable" error but after "importing list " new error came in the picture as shown below.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
imort list
data_cols=['user id','movie id','rating','timestamp']
item_cols=['movie id','movie title','release date','video release date','IMDb URL','unknown','Action','Adventure','Animation','Childrens','Comedy','Crime','Documentary','Drama','Fantasy','Film-Noir','Horror','Musical','Mystery','Romance ','Sci-Fi','Thriller','War' ,'Western']
user_cols = ['user id','age','gender','occupation','zip code']
#importing the data files onto dataframes
users=pd.read_csv('u.user',sep='|',names=user_cols,encoding='latin-1')
item=pd.read_csv('u.item',sep='|',names=item_cols,encoding='latin-1')
data=pd.read_csv('u.data',sep='\t',names=data_cols,encoding='latin-1')
dataset=pd.merge(pd.merge(item,data),users)
#print(dataset.head())
rating_total=dataset.groupby('movie title').size()
rating_mean=(dataset.groupby('movie title'))['movie title','rating']
rating_mean=rating_mean.mean()
rating_total=pd.DataFrame({'movie title':rating_total.index,'total 
ratings':rating_total.values})
rating_mean['movie title']=rating_mean.index
final=pd.merge(rating_mean,rating_total).sort_values(by='total 
ratings',ascending=False)
pop=final[:300].sort_values(by='rating',ascending=False)
pop=pop['movie title']
pop1=list(pop.head(10))
```

**Output**

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-57-0b36af3a9876> in <module>
     30 pop=pop['movie title']
     31 #print(pop.head())
---> 32 pop1=list(pop.head(10))

TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

Comment: your module `list` shadows the built in data structure `list`, when you are trying to do list(pop...) you mean the built in data type but are infact calling the module you imported! import your module under a different name, such as `import list as myList`

Comment: Again I'm getting .....TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-59-f8768e3fd4b3> in <module>
     30 pop=pop['movie title']
     31 #print(pop.head())
---> 32 pop1=myList(pop.head(10))

TypeError: 'module' object is not callable

Comment: you're doing the same thing. `myList` is a MODULE, does it have functions you want to use? are you trying to do `myList.my_function()`? you cant call `myList` directly, it wasnt designed to be called directly

Comment: when I restarted juypter notebook and run it again ....I've done. Thanks for your suggestions and time..... besides I'm working on movie recommender system project. Will you give some suggestions?